# saver.restore() issue in tensorflow 0.12 version

Tags: python, tensorflow

There is a problem with saver.restore in tensorflow 0.12 version. While i am saving the session to current directory, it is managed to save. But while i am trying to restoring the session, it is not working for same path. When i try with absolute path it is working.

Can anyone help me in solving this issue ?

```
import tensorflow as tf


constant = tf.Variable("This is constant")


saver = tf.train.Saver()

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()



with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(init)
    saver.restore(sess, 'sample_code')
    for i in range(4):
        print(sess.run(constant))

    saver.save(sess, 'sample_code')
```

Output :

```
NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for sample_code
```

Comment: `saver.save` returns the path at which the variables were saved. Try logging out the return value from the `saver.save(...)` call to see the path that it is saving too. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/state_ops/saving_and_restoring_variables

Comment: Thank you Shan Carter for your reply. I will try that thing and will check.

Comment: @ShanCarter - could you copy your comment to an answer, since it presumably seems to have worked for the OP?  Thanks!